# Reverse for loop with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a `li` that I want to animate while hovering over.

I try to get the previous `li` item with §(this).prevAll("li") and then use JQuery to change the style.

For this I want to get the IDs of the previous items. My current code looks like this:

```
 $("#somediv li").hover(function()
{
  var object = $(this).prevAll("li");

  var i;      
  for (i = object.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    dowork(i);
  }

  function dowork(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
        $("#"+object[i].id+"").addClass("animateprogress");
    }, 500 * i);
  }
```

Output of the for loop is 5,4,3,2,1,0 (depending on object length). The timeout output though reverses this to 0,1,2,3,4,5. I don't know why tough. I just want to output 5,4,3,2,1,0 with 500ms delay to style my previous `li` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to distinguish between the delay you want and the object index you want. Both are now the same variable `i` in your function, but they should be somewhat opposite.

So for example do:

```
$("#somediv li").hover(function() {
  var object = $(this).prevAll("li");

  var i;      
  for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    // pass a delay that increases with each iteration,
    // and pass an index that decreases with each iteration:
    dowork(500 * i, object.length - 1 - i);
  }

  function dowork(delay, index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(index);
        $("#"+object[index].id).addClass("animateprogress");
    }, delay);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
setTimeout(animate, (object.length - 1 - i) * 500)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these codes too

```
$("#somediv li").hover(function()
{
  var object = $(this).prevAll("li");

  var i;      
  for (i = object.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    dowork(i,(object.length-i)*500);
  }

  function dowork(i,d) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
        $("#"+object[i].id+"").addClass("animateprogress");
    }, d);
  }
```

It will give the result you expect.

The issue was on delay time you was adding greater time for greater number which is opposite of your expectation